A simple cross-number puzzle # 2
Beginner puzzle
This puzzle is intended to be suitable for people who are new to puzzle solving.
Clarification: Both experienced solvers and new solvers are welcome to post solutions to this puzzle.

Fill each square in this cross-number with a non-zero digit such that all of the conditions in the clues are satisfied. The digits used are not necessarily distinct.
1 ACROSS. A prime which is the sum of two squares
3 ACROSS. Twice the answer to 2 DOWN
1 DOWN. $p \times q$, where $p$, $q$ are prime and $q=p+4$
4 DOWN. $60$% of 5 ACROSS


This puzzle comes from the Senior Kangaroo 2021 contest.

A similar puzzle is here:  A simple cross-number puzzle

1 Down:

 $p$ cannot exceed 10 since $pq$ would be too large otherwise (not 2 digits). The possibilities are $p = 3, q = 7, pq = 21$ and $p = 7, q = 11, pq = 77$.
From 1 Down, 3 Across starts with either 1 or 7. Since 3 Across is twice 2 Down and the two are equal in length, 3 Across cannot start with 1, and 1 Down is 77.
7 ?
7 ? ?
  ? ?

1 Across:

 By Fermat's two-square theorem, a prime that is a sum of two squares is precisely a prime that is 1 modulo 4. The only 2-digit prime that is 1 modulo 4 and starts with 7 is 73 (= 64 + 9).
7 3
7 ? ?
  ? ?

Alternatively, you can

 deduce the top middle cell by seeing that half of 3 Across (7xx) must start with 3. This way you can simply ignore the clue for 1 Across.

4 Down & 5 Across:

 4 Down is 3/5 times 5 Across, and the two share the last digit. 5 Across must be a multiple of 5 (so that 3/5 of that is an integer), and then so is 4 Down (since the last digit is either 0 or 5). Therefore, 5 Across is a multiple of 25, i.e. one of 25, 50, or 75. 4 Down can be one of 15, 30, or 45. 
Since 3 Across is twice 2 Down, it is an even number, and it ends with an even digit. So 4 Down must start with an even digit, making it 45.
7 3
7 ? 4
  7 5

3 Across & 2 Down:

 We can write down an equation with a single unknown being the missing digit: $2(307 + 10x) = 704 + 10x$. Solving this gives $x = 9$.

Solution:

7 3
7 9 4
  7 5


Well explained!

A bit of different approach(more straightforward/bruteforced, less math knowledge) than Bubbler's answer:
1 ACROSS. A prime which is the sum of two squares

 1 across is 2 digits, so we can have values between 13($3^2 + 2^2$) and 98($7^2 + 7^2)$

3 ACROSS. Twice the answer to 2 DOWN

 2 down must be at most 499(otherwise 3 across would become 4 digits). That means that 1 across can only end in 1, 2, 3 or 4
 Using Excel and conditional formatting, I limited the possible values for 1 across to the following:
 13, 32, 34, 41, 52, 53, 61, 64, 72, 73, 74, 81, 82

1 DOWN. p×q, where p, q are prime and q=p+4

 First few prime numbers are 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23
 With difference of 4 we get a few groups: (3, 7), (7, 11), (13, 17), (17, 23)
 We also see that $13*17=221$, but 1 down is only 2 digits, so we only have 2 options for 1 down: 21 or 77
 But given that 1 across can not start with 2, the only possible answer for 1 down is 77.
 That also limits 1 across to 72, 73 or 74
 Also, hint 2 suggests that 3 across(that starts with 7) is double of 2 down. That leaves only 1 possibility of 1 across = 73(because highest double of 2xx is $299*2 = 598$ and lowest double of 4xx is $400*2 = 800$)

4 DOWN. 60% of 5 ACROSS

 With both numbers being 2 digits and sharing the last digit, we can limit the possible values to:
 (25, 15), (75, 45)
 So first digit of 4 down is either 1 or 4, but 3 across is double of 2 down, so the last digit of 3 across must be even. That leaves us with only 1 possibility for 4 down: 45
 That means that 5 across is 75

So far we have:

 7  3
7  x  4
   7  5

Now to find the remaining digits:

 3 x 7 +
3 x 7
 ---
7 x 4

   14
  2x
6

 Last digit of 2x+1 = x and 2x+1 must be between 11 and 19(otherwise the sum would be either 6x4 or 8x4)
 Therefore x = 9(18+1 = 19)

So the answer is:

 7  3
7  9  4
   7  5

And fit it back to the hints:
1 ACROSS. A prime which is the sum of two squares

 $8^2 + 3^2 = 64 + 9 = 73$

3 ACROSS. Twice the answer to 2 DOWN

 $397 * 2 = 794$

1 DOWN. p×q, where p, q are prime and q=p+4

 $p = 7, q = 11, p*q = 7 * 11 = 77$

4 DOWN. 60% of 5 ACROSS

 $75 * 60% = 45$

